# Using split in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have used StorageFile to read some contents from file. Below is the code...

```
StorageFile fileAsync = await this.roamingFolder.GetFileAsync(item_filename);
String str = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileAsync);
String[] strArrays = new String[5];
strArrays = str.Split(new Char[] { '\n' });

Item myItem = new Item();
myItem.ItemFileName = item_filename;
```

The contents are entered and retrieved in a textbox in which I declared `AcceptsReturn = "True"`. Here is the problem, if i didn't used the `AcceptsReturn` then the contents are retrieved properly but if used then if the user types something into textbox and presses enter to continue in nextline and at the time of retrieval, the contents that entered before the first newline are only read, not the remaining characters. Need help.

Comment: It's not clear what `Split` has to do with your problem. Change it to `strArrays = new String[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }` and see if the problem still exists. if so, then you know that the problem is unrelated to the file I/O or to the Split.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried to change it and still the problem exist. And also if i delete the `strArrays = str.Split(new Char[] { '\n' });` line then nothing is getting retrieved, its totally blank.

Comment: Good. Now you have shown that `Split` has nothing to do with your problem. Therefore, the answer to your question "Why do I have a problem with `Split`?" is "There is no problem with `Split`." The problem is in code you did not include in your question.

Comment: But i dont know where did i made the mistake. Do you have any guess why this error occurs?

Comment: You need to debug the code that retrieves the text from the textbox.